# Iterating over ActiveRecord_Relation, make changes then save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, `foo.rb`. A user can have many "foos". I want to select a specific "foo", make change to their table column then save all at once:

```
f = Foo.where(bar: 1) # returns, say, four objects.
```

Now, I want to change: `bar: 10`, then save:

```
f.map do |x| x.bar = 10 end
```

How do you save? I cannot figure this out in irb. Is it possible with less code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all):

```
Foo.where(bar: 1).update_all(bar: 10)
```

Comment: So simple and clean. Thanks.